# Augmented Reality showing error when using metaio sdk

Tags: android, augmented-reality, metaio

I am trying to implement AR in my project and i have included the Metaio sdk version 4.5 for AR.I also created a image to be scanned using the metaio creator.The problem that i am facing right now is that when i try to scan the image using the device camera,the image which was uploaded in metaio creator is been fetched and is shown.It doesn't show AR.It also shows a Note message as:no Google analytic's id is set. Don't know where to set this Google analytic's id.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess you should go through this tutorial first. http://dev.metaio.com/creator/tutorials/

Comment: @Meghs Thanks.i found where to set the Google analytic's id.its in the details  option after you create a new channel and upload a new image.If u don't have a a Google analytic id ,then just set it as none.